# semantic ui sidebar not working in angular

Tags: angular, semantic-ui

i tried to create a sidebar using semantic ui in angular. but it is not working, when i click the button i get the error in console that the .sidebar function is not found in jquery.
this is my component html:

```
<div class="ui sidebar inverted vertical menu">
 <a class="item">
  1
 </a>
 <a class="item">
  2
 </a>
 <a class="item">
  3
 </a>
</div>
<div class="pusher">
 <button class="ui button toggle">toggle</button>
</div>
```

my component ts code is :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from '../../../node_modules/jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.component.less']
})
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $('.toggle').click(
       function () {
        $('.ui.sidebar')
          .sidebar('toggle')
          ;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

i get this error in console.

```
ERROR TypeError: _node_modules_jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__(...).sidebar is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (editor.component.ts:17)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5183)
at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4991)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:16147)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
at HTMLButtonElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1770)
```

Comment: I strongly recommend not using Jquery in an angular app. Whatever you can achieve with jquery angular has a way for it.

Comment: but don't semantic use jquery?, how could i use those components!